# Controlling alignment in group of equations with align / aligned

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align, gather, flalign

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
    x &= 1 & y &= 233 & z &= 2
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned}
    a &= 44444444444444444444 & c &= 545554
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

What I get

[image]

What I need

[image]

I need it only for one group of equations, so I don't want to load `fleqn`. I tried using `flalign`, adding `&` at the end of the aligned, or `\RaggedLeft` from `ragged2e`, but nothing worked.

I can make them centered with `gather` instead of `align`, but can't make them flushed left.

Comment: what is the intention of the `aligned` here? they only have one row so there is no alignment possible?

Comment: just use a standard `align` with a single `&` before the first = on each row and no nested environments, that is the only alignment point you want, so the only place you need `&`

Comment: Right, my original set of equations was with aligned rows but I ended up splitting them. I didn't think about removing the `&` as well, and ended up making things overly complicated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a single `align` environment and a single alignment point per row?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    x &= 1 \quad  y = 233 \quad  z = 2 \\
    a &= 44444444444444444444 \quad  c = 545554
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just going to post same, but with qquad:-)

Comment: The simplest way seems to be always the best way! +1